# How to integrate Quasar UI into Astro SSG

Tags: javascript, integration, quasar-framework, astrojs, static-site-generation

I want to generate static site with Astro generator (https://astro.build/) and I want to use Quasar UI components (https://quasar.dev/) on the site.

I found, I can set Vue app entry point in Astro config (`astro.config.mjs`):

```js
import {defineConfig} from 'astro/config';
import vue from "@astrojs/vue";

// https://astro.build/config
export default defineConfig({
    integrations: [vue({appEntrypoint: '/src/pages/_app'})]
});
```

This is my `./src/pages/_app.mjs`:

```js
import {Quasar} from "quasar";
export default (app) => {
    app.use(Quasar, {config: {}});
}
```

I have an error on `astro dev`:

```
TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.assign (<anonymous>)
    at installQuasar (/.../astro/node_modules/quasar/dist/quasar.cjs.prod.js:6:15454)
    at Object.install (/.../astro/node_modules/quasar/dist/quasar.cjs.prod.js:6:491344)
    at Object.use (/.../astro/node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.cjs.js:4377:28)
    at __vite_ssr_exports__.default (/src/pages/_app.mjs:6:9)
    at Object.renderToStaticMarkup (@astrojs/vue/server.js:22:30)
    at renderFrameworkComponent (/node_modules/astro/dist/runtime/server/render/component.js:178:66)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

How can I integrate Quasar UI into Astro SSG?

Answer (score 3):

Not a solution, but the answer to your question seems to be that Quasar UI cannot be currently integrated into any SSR or server-side rendering framework (including SSG or static site generation) except Quasar itself.

The only [Quasar flavour](https://quasar.dev/start/pick-quasar-flavour) that seems to be compatible with [Astro's Vue.js integration docs](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/integrations-guide/vue/#appentrypoint) seems to be the [Vite plugin](https://quasar.dev/start/vite-plugin) route, which as you mentioned, results in the `TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object` error.

The incompatibility of Quasar's Vite plugin with SSR is mentioned explicitly in Quasar's docs:

> Warning! Limitation ahead:
> SSR builds with our Vite plugin are not supported (only through our Quasar CLI with Vite).

In any case these are other things I tried, just in case someone finds it useful for further investigation:

`astro.config.mjs`:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'astro/config';
import vue from '@astrojs/vue';
import { Quasar } from 'quasar'; // Tried importing Quasar here as well

// https://astro.build/config
export default defineConfig({
    integrations: [vue({ jsx: true, appEntrypoint: '/src/pages/_app' })] // Added jsx: true
    vite: {
        plugins: [Quasar], // Plugins can be specified here as well
        ssr: {
            noExternal: ['quasar'] // Read bellow
        },
    },
});
```

The `ssr: { noExternal: [] }` usage idea was taken from [here](https://blog.logrocket.com/building-multi-framework-dashboard-with-astro/#adding-ui-frameworks) and makes the error change to `ReferenceError: window is not defined at /node_modules/.pnpm/quasar@2.12.2/node_modules/quasar/dist/quasar.esm.prod.js:6:1453` which makes it more clear that the Vite Quasar plugin needs the windows object and thus can only work on the client.

`/src/pages/_app.mjs`:

```
import { Quasar } from 'quasar';
export default (app) => {
    app.use(Quasar, {config: {}});
}
```

Also, I found https://github.com/freddy38510/quasar-app-extension-ssg

Comment: Does this approach work?

Comment: No, I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Great try though <3
Too bad it didnt work, would totally work with a setup like this

Answer (score 0):

```
import {Quasar} from "quasar";
export default (app) => {
    app.use(Quasar, {config: {}});
}
```

Problem with this code is that app.use require object with install as method, which Quasar object doesnt have, even if you manage to import object with install it will through out of module error.

**Suggestion**:
Simply use UMD module provided by quasar.

Comment: Quasar UMD is not compatible with SSG or SSR though, it only runs on the client?